# Mathematical expression in Crystal Reports

Tags: math, crystal-reports, command

I have two fields in a Crystal Report.  Open and InProgress. Each field is a result of a separate command.

In my report, I have bound `{Open}` and `{InProgress}` to a text field. I want to create a third field with an expression like `{Open} - {InProgress}` that will calculate the difference.

Can I do this with such an expression, if yes how can it be acomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a decent solution. If there is a better way, I will gladly accept that as the answer.

What I did was create a Formula Field, then put the expression I had above `{Open} - {InProgress}` into that field. I can now use the formula field in the report.

Comment: There are really only two ways to do it, one of which is what you did. The other is to create a view (or calculated field, or stored process) in the database and include that in the report. Using a Crystal formula is the better way to do it in most cases.